# Django RadioSelect widget, add additional information

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have this simplified model and form:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class BookForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['Field'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, empty_label=None, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
        self.fields['Field'].queryset = Books.objects.all()
        self.fields['Field'].initial = Books.objects.filter(default=True).first()
```

This will result in a RadioSelect-Form, like this:

```
(x) Book1
( ) Book2
( ) Book3
```

My problem is, how can I add the price in the RadioSelect form, that it's just visible.
It should appear after the name of the book, ideally even in a different font, which I set over a bootstrap class (e.g "text-primary") (this is not mandatory)

```
(x) Book1 (10 €)
( ) Book2 (20 €)
( ) Book3 (30 €)
```

I know i can return the name and price in the model, like

```
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s €)' % (self.value, str(self.price))
```

But because of other reasons, i can not do this. I just need to return the name. Are there other ways to do this?

I even read into django-crispy-forms, but couldnt find a solution.

Comment: if you cannot concatenate the label, I believe that information is not inside your model or something closer ...  So I believe the challenge remains on form instance... Its possible to use an ajax ? a javascript  that load the extra data from an endpoint (URL) and concatenate it on the client side ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but i'm not that familiar with ajax/javascript. Maybe i have to concatenate the label and strip the price at a later point, which is a little hacky solultion imo.

Comment: where that extra  information  is ?  inside your database someway or you have to grab it from another site (or external service) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.label_from_instance`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

> The `__str__()` method of the model will be called to generate string representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices. To provide customized representations, subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance`.

You can define a function that gives you the representation that you want and then set `.label_from_instance` on your field.

Your `BookForm` then looks like this:

```
class BookForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['Field'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, empty_label=None, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
        self.fields['Field'].queryset = Books.objects.all()
        self.fields['Field'].initial = Books.objects.filter(default=True).first()
        # customize how your option is rendered in the template
        self.fields["Field"].label_from_instance = lambda item: f"{item} ({item.price} €)"
```

To apply CSS on the label add HTML. Instead of using `style='...'` you can also use classes so it works with Bootstrap.

```
self.fields["Field"].label_from_instance = lambda item: f"{item} <span style='color:red;'>({item.price} €)</span>"
```

For Python versions before 3.7:

```
self.fields["Field"].label_from_instance = lambda item: str(item) + "<span style='color:red;'>(" + str(item.price) + " €)</span>"
```

Then render your form in the template like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'books' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden_field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <ul>
    {% for choice in form.Field %}
        <li>{{ choice.choice_label|safe }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Iterate over the choices for your field and then you can get your customized labels with:

```
{{ choice.choice_label|safe }}
```

The [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) filter is needed so your HTML is not escaped.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you elaborate a little on this lambda function and where item is coming from?

Comment: The lambda function gets the `Book` instances when the template is being rendered, to get the labels. You could use a normal function with one argument instead of the lambda as well, it just needs to be something callable, and then return what you want the label to look like in the rendered template.

Comment: A little remark, Format ("f") strings have not been introduced before Python 3.6. You recommend future-fstrings or is there a different way to write it for python 3.5 ?

Comment: I've added a way to do it without f-strings, you could also do it with `.format()` instead but I find f-strings to be much nicer than the alternatives.

Comment: This works too for python 3.5 and before: lambda obj: "%s + (+ %s €)" % (obj, obj.price)